# Why does notifyAll() sometimes have no effect?

Tags: java, concurrency, java-threads

I've created this program:

```java
public class NotifyTest {
    public synchronized void sendNotify() {
        notifyAll();
    }

    public synchronized void receiveNotifies(int notifies) {
        while (notifies > 0) {
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
            notifies--;
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " left wait(), decremented notifies, current notifies count " + notifies);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        NotifyTest notifyTest = new NotifyTest();
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            Thread t1 = new Thread(() -> {
                notifyTest.receiveNotifies(4);
            });
            t1.setName("receiveNotifiesThread: " + i);
            t1.start();
        }

        System.out.println("Waiting until all receivers are started. Every Thread should be stopped after 4 notifies");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (Exception e) {}

        new Thread(() -> {
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                System.out.println("Sent notify " + i);
                notifyTest.sendNotify();
                try {
                    Thread.sleep((int) Math.random());
                } catch (Exception e) {}
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

Usually all threads should be stopped after 4 `sendNotify()`-calls. Anyways, when I run this program, it sometimes hangs, because the `receiveNotify()`-threads missed to receive a notification. The output looks like this when the program hangs:

```
> Waiting until all receivers are started. Every Thread should be stopped after 4 notifies
> Sent notify 0
> receiveNotifiesThread: 8 left wait(), decremented notifies, current notifies count 3
> receiveNotifiesThread: 7 left wait(), decremented notifies, current notifies count 3
> receiveNotifiesThread: 6 left wait(), decremented notifies, current notifies count 3
> receiveNotifiesThread: 5 left wait(), decremented notifies, current notifies count 3
> receiveNotifiesThread: 4 left wait(), decremented notifies, current notifies count 3
> receiveNotifiesThread: 3 left wait(), decremented notifies, current notifies count 3
> Sent notify 1
> receiveNotifiesThread: 2 left wait(), decremented notifies, current notifies count 3
> receiveNotifiesThread: 1 left wait(), decremented notifies, current notifies count 3
> receiveNotifiesThread: 0 left wait(), decremented notifies, current notifies count 3
> Sent notify 2
> Sent notify 3
> receiveNotifiesThread: 0 left wait(), decremented notifies, current notifies count 2
> receiveNotifiesThread: 1 left wait(), decremented notifies, current notifies count 2
> receiveNotifiesThread: 2 left wait(), decremented notifies, current notifies count 2
> receiveNotifiesThread: 3 left wait(), decremented notifies, current notifies count 2
> receiveNotifiesThread: 4 left wait(), decremented notifies, current notifies count 2
> receiveNotifiesThread: 5 left wait(), decremented notifies, current notifies count 2
> receiveNotifiesThread: 6 left wait(), decremented notifies, current notifies count 2
> receiveNotifiesThread: 7 left wait(), decremented notifies, current notifies count 2
> receiveNotifiesThread: 8 left wait(), decremented notifies, current notifies count 2
> receiveNotifiesThread: 8 left wait(), decremented notifies, current notifies count 1
> receiveNotifiesThread: 7 left wait(), decremented notifies, current notifies count 1
> receiveNotifiesThread: 6 left wait(), decremented notifies, current notifies count 1
> receiveNotifiesThread: 5 left wait(), decremented notifies, current notifies count 1
> receiveNotifiesThread: 4 left wait(), decremented notifies, current notifies count 1
> receiveNotifiesThread: 3 left wait(), decremented notifies, current notifies count 1
> receiveNotifiesThread: 2 left wait(), decremented notifies, current notifies count 1
> receiveNotifiesThread: 1 left wait(), decremented notifies, current notifies count 1
> receiveNotifiesThread: 0 left wait(), decremented notifies, current notifies count 1
```

Do you have any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Whats a `myNotify()-Thread`?

Comment: Please provide a [MRE].

Comment: notifyAll wakes up **all** threads that are in 'wait'.    A thread executing myNotify does not seem to use 'wait', so it will not be woken out of the wait - thus I'm unclear on what you are saying. FWIW you should have a design where the meaning of being awoken is to go and check for some state; don't just assume that **because** you were woken, the awaited state is sure to be true.

Comment: Hi all, 

thank you very much for the answers. So I would like to have the following situation:

- if a notifyAll() is sent, every Thread should just decrement the int variable notifies
- every Thread must receive the notifyAll()
- it should not be the case, that multiple notifies are overlapped, means it should not be the case that a Thread misses to receive a notify

I will add a test example in a few minutes.

Comment: Feel free to accept my answer because it is the solution. Keep in mind that it takes time to write one. If something is not clear to you, add a comment to it and let me know it.

Answer (score 0):

When you send the notifications ...

```java
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                System.out.println("Sent notify " + i);
                notifyTest.sendNotify();
                try {
                    Thread.sleep((int) Math.random());
                } catch (Exception e) {}
            }
```

... you let the thread sleep for `(int) Math.random()` milliseconds. The function `Math.random()` returns a `double` that is between `0.0` and `1.0` exclusively. Casting that to `int` gives you `0`. So you let the thread sleep for `0` milliseconds.

The waiting threads print to the console when they get woken up, which takes time. If your notifier-thread doesn't sleep at all (`0` milliseconds) and sends out notifications right after the previous ones, the waiter-threads could not have reached the `wait`-call and therefore the notifications have no effect.

To solve that, simply avoid the zero in the `sleep`-call, e.g.:

```java
                try {
                    Thread.sleep((int) (Math.random() * 100 + 1));
                } catch (Exception e) {}
```